# In ASP.Net SqlBulkCopy getting error like The provider could not determine the Double value.

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.Net SqlBulkCopy getting error like The provider could not determine the Double value. For example, the row was just created, the default for the Double column was not available, and the consumer had not yet set a new Double value.

AS using providers as for 2003:
 ExelconnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filname + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0;\"";

and 2007 as:

"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filname + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;";

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
    string xlsFile = AsyncFileUpload1.FileName;  
            if (AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string Extension = Path.GetExtension(AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/xl/" + FileName);
                if (Extension == ".xls")
                {
                    AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(FilePath);
                    Session.Add("s_FilePath", FilePath);



                    string excelConnectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + "; Extended Properties = 'Excel 4.0;HDR=YES;'";

                    OleDbConnection xlsConn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

                    try
                    {
                //Do something
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                //Handly exception
            }
            finally
            {
            }
```

If you find it useful, please mark it as your answer else me know...

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the excel sheet **column contains numbers** are in a correct format or very big numbers are there.